# How to handle quotes in quotes in quotes with jinja/html?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, quotes

I can find many posts about escapiang quotes for rendering them on a page, but in my case I want to make

> ```
>                <button onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for("admin.pairs(entry.id)") }}';">
>                    PP
>                </button>
> ```

So onclick is followed by something that needs to be in quotes, and inside I have href which is followed by something else that needs to be in quotes, which is followed by url_for which contains something that needs to be in quotes. So I try to change between single and double quotes as such: " ' "" ' ", but it is not working. So in this case, which quotes need to be escaped? Or is it about something else?

Comment: What does your code look like when rendered?

Comment: In the error message it looked the same as here (the page wouldn't actually render). I also hadn't got how to pass values to url_for correctly so that created errors too. Now both the line and the page shows how it's supposed to,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to store the result of `url_for` in a variable and use it instead of calling `url_for`.

```html
{% set url = url_for("admin.pairs(entry.id)") %}

<button onclick="window.location.href='{{ url }}';">PP</button>
```